# Execvp() is not accepting 'ls' as Argument

Tags: c

```
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #define MAX_LIMIT 20 
 int main () {


printf("Shell> ");

    char str1[MAX_LIMIT]; 
    fgets(str1, MAX_LIMIT, stdin);    
    char delim[] =" ";
    char *parsed;
    int index = 0;
    char *cmd[index];

    parsed = strtok(str1,delim);    
    while( parsed != NULL) {
        cmd[index] = parsed;
        index++;        
        parsed = strtok(NULL, delim); 
     }   
    cmd[index] = NULL;
    int wow = fork();
    if(wow == 0){   
      execvp((char*)cmd[0],cmd);            
        }
    return(0);
    }
```

Everything above is working fine except execvp() 
cmd[0] receives string 'ls', technically execvp() should display the list but it doesn't. 
If I replace cmd[0] with 'ls', it works.

Comment: `char *cmd[index];` is an array of size zero.

Comment: Index is being incremented while parsing.

Comment: It is zero when the array is defined. It is not going to reallocate the array magically when the `index` is changing, C is not working like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two main issues here.

First when you declare your array as `char *cmd[index];`, the size of the array is **not** tied to current value of `index` as `index` changes.  It sets the size to the **current** value of `index` which is 0.  Creating an array of size 0 invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  You need to set a fixed size for the array that will be big enough for your needs.

```
char *cmd[MAX_LIMIT];
```

The other problem is your choice of delimiters.  The `fgets` function reads a line of text *including the newline at the end of the input*.  So whichever parameter is read last will have a `\n` at the end of it.  To fix this, add `\n` to the delimiter list.

```
char delim[] =" \n";
```